# how to concatenate a stirng text with a value of config in table core_config_data

Tags: patches

hello everyone i want to concatenate a string with a value in the table core_config_data i have the path and I don't know how to do it by patches

> PS : i am usign magento 2.3

`if anyone can help me i will be grateful`

Comment: Have you any idea that how to get core_config_data value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get "store_config_data" value like below

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\PackageName\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    const XML_SINGLE_STORE = 'general/single_store_mode/enabled';
    const CUSTOM_FIELD_PATH = 'general/support/customname';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve store config value
     * @param  string $path
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getConfig($path, $scope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $id = null)
    {
        if($this->isSingleStoreMode()){
            return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($path,'default',0);
        }
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($path, $scope, $id);
    }

    /**
     * Check store is in single store mode
     * @method isSingleStoreMode
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isSingleStoreMode()
    {
        $stores = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
        if(count($stores) > 1){
            return false;
        }

        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_SINGLE_STORE);
    }

    public function getCustomFieldValue()
    {
        return $this->getConfig(self::CUSTOM_FIELD_PATH);
    }
}
```

Above i have created one common function to get storec onfig value.

Now please call this helper function getCustomFieldValue() anywhere you want.

Now according to your requirement please write below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        
$helper = $objectManager->get('\Namespace\PackageName\Helper\Data');
$coreConfigValue = $helper->getCustomFieldValue();

$customStringVal = "Test";

$finalString = $customStringVal.' '.coreConfigValue;
echo $finalString;
```